# Proper way of adding CSS file in Vue.js Application

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

What is the proper way of adding external CSS file in Vue.js Application ?

I found several ways to add CSS file in Vue.js Application.

Some one suggest to use this one. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bootstrap.min.css">`.

Some one suggest this one

```
<style lang="scss">
@import 'src/assets/css/mycss_lib.css';
</style>
```

Some one suggest this one

`require('./assets/layout3/css/layout.min.css')`

Some one suggest to use below code in `webpack.config.js`.

```
{
    test: /\.(css|less)$/,
    use: [{
         loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
    }, {
         loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
    }, {
         loader: "less-loader" // compiles Less to CSS
    }]
  }
```

Some one suggest to use this one

```
<style src="../node_modules/vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"></style>
```

What are the merits and demerits of using all those ways ?

I would like to use in a way so that all CSS files become a single file at the time of deployment. So that my application loads faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for me(!) in Vue.js is to include global page-styles in my main index.html with a link tag. This way they are accessible from everywhere and are loaded when the page is first opened.
Like this:
*index.html:*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The style-rules for my components are inlined in .vue-files using: *mycomponent.vue:*

```
<style scoped>
...
</style>
```

EDIT:

If you don't want to use .vue files and work with .js files you can not scope the css inside components. If thats the case I always name them the same as the component and also include it inside index.html in link tag.

Comment: Thanks @informant09. I have several style sheets. Should I include them using several `<link>` tag ?

Comment: Yes one Link Tag for each  style. Feel free to Post your changes.

Answer (score 7):

1. Install sass

```
npm install sass-loader --save-dev
```

2. Create new `css` directory under your `src/assets` directory
3. Create a `styles.scss` file in the new `css` directory
4. Add the following line of code to your `main.js` file

```
import '../src/assets/css/styles.scss';
```

In the `styles.scss` file you can import multiple css files.

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.min.css';
@import './common.css';
```

You can also write regular CSS properties like this in the same file

```
body {
  background: gray;
}

div {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

5. Restart your dev server

```
npm run serve
```